# How can start 2 or more Azure Instance at a same time

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

How can start 2 or more Azure VM (IaaS) Instances at a same time via their control panel ?
Thank you.

Comment: Instance of what?  VM? Cloud Service? Web Site? Mobile Service?

Comment: VM. I can not see any option to set how many instances to create. Just 1 by 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can't explicitly do that with IaaS (i.e. Windows Azure VM). You can only do this with PaaS (i.e. Cloud Service - WebRole, WorkerRole or Web Sites).

Azure VM, part of Infrastructure services does not provide this functionality out of the box. You have to manage VM creation/start/stop and VM deletion, and content synchronization on your own. This is the drawback of using Infrastructure Services.